# How to support Custom Completion Dictionary in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4

XCode 3 can support customize completion dictionary by plugin ODCompletionDictionary.
When I try to use it in code 4, it doesn't work.
Does any know how to customize completion dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know as well. I used Completion Dictionary extensively previously.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem there will be support for XCode 4, but [Kevin Ross converted](http://www.twentyfourmountains.com/codecognizance/2011/04/19/converted-odcompletion-dictionary-macros-for-xcode-4/) base macros and provided a script for converting your custom ones.